# In what order does scandir() load files?

Tags: php

Is it by date of file creation, alphabet, asc, desc or a combination of two or more of these criteria?

Comment: @Devon I wonder that as well but I mostly find it's easier to ask on SO. How about you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)**:

> By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in ascending order. If the optional **`sorting_order`** is set to `SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING`, then the sort order is alphabetical in descending order. If it is set to `SCANDIR_SORT_NONE` then the result is unsorted.